# Azure Mobile service (dot net backend) running locally, throws unauthorized error

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, iis-express, azure-mobile-services

I've created a fresh new Dot Net backend based Azure Mobile service, downloaded it, published the service part to azure with publish settings. This all works fine.

(this is the default to do app that Azure Mobile service generates, no changes made it to it.)

Now for development & debugging purpose I need to connect with my local service. Following is what I've done

1. Updated "applicationhost.config" IIS express file to have a new binding type

where 192.168.2.6 is my local internal IP

2. Run VS 2013 in Admin mode.
3. Set both project as startup project from solution
4. Updated following code in App.Xaml.cs

   public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
           "http:// 192.168.2.6:59984/"
       );
5. Run
6. Browser opens to show the service running & WP8 emulator starts loading the app.

This is what happens 
I can see the service up & live on localhost:59984, I can also see in IIS Express toolbar icon that http:// 192.168.2.6:59984 is also running the local service just fine. Click open it & it shows the default "Service Up & Running" page

The WP8 emulator starts, Application Loads & I get a 
"The request could not be completed. (unauthorized)" error.

Please check the image below

[image]

I've also run a ntash command to allow IIS express for remote connections. as mentioned in [This Blog](http://gilesey.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/allowing-remote-access-to-your-iis-express-service/)

can someone please help? I've been struggling with this for over 2 days now & what seems like a very simple thing, is driving me nuts now.

Thanks 
Supreet Tare

Comment: Could it be that you must configure the phone app to access Internet/Network services of the phone?

Comment: Have you looked at those instructions to connect the WP8 emulator to localhost? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/em-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately that's not helping. If you see my original post above I've already updated the config file to use IP address & to make it available from other remote devices. Also tried deploying the site to IIS instead of IIS Express, that is not helping either. I am at loss with this one. There must be something very small that I am missing some place..

Comment: interestingly, if I follow the same steps with a locally developed Web API Asp.Net project all works just fine.

Comment: following the same steps with a locally developed Web API Asp.Net project all works just fine.1.Create a new Asp.Net Project 2. Run it to have an entry in applicationhost.config file. 3. Update binding in the above file with IP address.5.OPen Web Project props in VS & change localhost to IP address, create a virtual directory.6.Disable firewall 7.Run VS in Admin Mode & open the same URL from WP8 emulator & an Ipad on same network. Both devices showing the test json values returned from the test API. Its only the Mobile service project that is not connecting & asking for authentication.

Comment: Hi Carlo, I followed your blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/04/10/creating-an-azure-mobile-services-net-backend-from-scratch.aspx & it worked fine. But to follow along your blog & to add a Mobile service enabled WP8 project to the solution, I needed to install vs2013 update 2 RC because Microsoft.bcl 1.8 library requires nuget 2.8, which can only be installed with vs2013 update 2. Once I had the update installed your solution worked fine & also the sample solution from Azure worked just fine. I hope this helps someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 & everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david_kidder/archive/2014/06/03/dave-is-getting-upset-episode-1-trying-to-get-my-windows-phone-to-talk-to-my-locally-running-net-backend-mobile-service.aspx)

> You need to specify the application key of the service in the Web.config file:
>
> `<add key="MS_ApplicationKey" value="Overriden by portal settings" />`
>
> If you run the service within Visual Studio, you don't need these values, and every request will pass. When you deploy the service on Azure, these values are overriden with the correct values. But, if you deploy the Mobile Service on your local IIS, you need to manually set them, and be sure that they match the values you enter in the client.
>
> After changing the MS_ApplicationKey value in the web.config and also updating my phone client app to specify the application key in the MobileServiceClient constructor, I was able to hit the service from the phone!